# Typo3 v9.5.4 content elements couldn't be applied

Tags: typo3, element, typo3-9.x

I'm totally new in this CMS, When I'm trying to add/change the content elements it just don't work, only the tab title does. I wonder if I have missed something up during the configuration?

[config_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeXDO.png)

[result_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJjd8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems like you don't have a template that renders actual content.

If you just want to test TYPO3 you should probably get a theme extension like https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/bootstrap_package/ (there are many other themes as well). You can simply install the extension, choose a root page and add it to the TypoScript template https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptIn45MinutesTutorial/latest/TypoScriptOverview/MainTemplate/

If you are going to develop a site with your own template, using a site package is the recommended way. You can use https://sitepackagebuilder.com/new/ to generate a package that comes with a lot of useful functionality and configuration already available. Have a look here for further information: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SitePackageTutorial/